# Сортировка обьектов по приоритетам

Tags: django

Прошу помочь с одной делемой, есть у меня обьекты, примеру меню там 'Первое Второе Десерты Напитки' и потом вспомнил что есть еще один обьект, он должен находиться вторым по списку, как сделать так что бы,я мог давать приоритеты обектам что бы они были своих местах

Comment: положить их в список не подойдёт ?

Comment: @Интик я же в jinja через for выведу, через список не получиться, может есть другой вариант

Comment: Ну так добавьте им поле для хранения приоритета и делайте сортировку при выборке. В чём проблема?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ок я задал в модели integer, теперь как делать сортировку, можно пример, спасибо

Comment: @JuniorDjango https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by